# Issues linking CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to do a simple HTML page using VS Code, but I'm running into issues with the CSS linking to the HTML.

I *think* my folder structure is good, as I have some images linked in the document further down the line that is being called correctly.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="./resources/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

resources/css/style.css:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  background-image: url(./resources/images/pattern.jpeg);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: khaki;
}
```

I've also read on some other threads about making sure to have <meta charset="utf-8"> set and I've also used NotePad++ to make sure the files are encoded correctly. Interestingly when I closed and reopened VS Code to check the encoding, the CSS loaded as I expected, but then wouldn't update any further.

I hope that makes sense, please let me know if I can clarify anything further, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure? Also, the CSS you posted is inside the `style.css` or is it really in the html document? Most important, have you checked the network tab of devTools to see if the CSS file is being loaded?

Comment: From what I can surmise.. you background-image path should actually be `background-image: url(./images/pattern.jpg)`

Comment: Looking at your question again.. can you clarify:

Are you referring to an intellisense issue in VS Code when you're talking about "linking" - or do you mean that when you load the index.html in a browser that the CSS is not being loaded? If it is the latter, vscode is not then related to your issue.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting in the original post and likely this one!

My folder structure is as follows
Source folder
  index.html 
  resources folder
    CSS folder
      style.css
    Images folder
      Images 1, 2, 3 etc

the CSS code is inside the style.css file.


I was referring to CSS not being loaded when viewing index.html in the preview pane.

However, my changes are loaded if I close and reopen the folder in VSC, or occasionally when I save the HTML & CSS. I appreciate I don't really know what I'm talking about so I do apologise! I appreciate the time

Comment: Have you tried viewing your page inside of a browser (was not aware vscode had a preview pane)?

And is this your file structure:

**baseFolder/index.html** •
**baseFolder/resources/css/style.css** •
**baseFolder/resources/images/**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Oh yeah, that works.., the preview panel updates in real-time which looked pretty neat. When I've got my HTML file open in VCS there's a preview option in the top right under minimise/close etc. looks like a split window with a magnifying glass in the corner. Yes thats my file structure!

Comment: I've just found my main issue is actually a bad extension in VSC... I was using HTML Preview which adds the option I mentioned above. Rather embarrassing! Sorry for wasting your time, thank you though!